# How can i Access the table added in Word or Excel and iterate throght each and every row and cell using Office.js

Tags: javascript, add-in, office-js, office-app

Is it possible to iterate through table rows and column after it is added in the document or worksheet.

I am using the following code to add a table and I want on the success of this code i should be able to access the rows and column should be able to replace the values of cells after some conversion. Bellow is the code that i am using to create the table.

```
     var tableData = new Office.TableData();
            var headers = [placeholder.columns.map(function (c) { return c.column; })];
            tableData.headers = headers
            tableData.rows = rows;
            var document = Office.context.document;

            document.setSelectedDataAsync(tableData, function (result) {
                var placeholder = Office.context.document.settings.get(results.binding.id);
                    if (officeCallSucceded(result, true)) {
                        document.bindings.addFromSelectionAsync(Office.BindingType.Table, function (result) {
                            if (officeCallSucceded(result)) {
                               //SOME  LOGIC FOR BINDING HERE TO ADD //EVENT handlers to the table just added
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here's the code to retrieve any individual row of a [Table](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/table) in Excel:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    // substitute 'Table1' with the table you want and '0' with your row index
    var myRow = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem('Table1').rows.getItemAt(0);
    myRow.load('values');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(myRow.values);
    });
});
```

To replace content in a row:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var myNewRow = [["a", "b", "c"]];
    // substitute 'Table1' with the table you want and '0' with your row
    var row = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem('Table1').rows.getItemAt(0);
    row.values = myNewRow;
    return ctx.sync();
});
```

In Word there's a similar TableRowCollection.getItem method, but it's still in preview: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/word/resources/tablerowcollection.md#getitemindex-number

Comment: thanks for your reply @Michael but with code i will be able to replace the values of cell ??

Comment: thanks @Michael  this works i tried some code for word as well that i will mention . I was asking this question because in cell there is html thats coming from DB and I wanted that html in cell i should be able to access that i am able to access now but not able to convert the cell html into normal text. :(

Comment: //this code is for two rows and two columns table that can be chnaged as per need 
        Word.run(function (ctx) {
            var table = ctx.document.body.tables.first;
            ctx.load(table);
            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
               table.values[0][0] = [["<h1>One</h1>", "<h1>Two</h1>"], ["<p>Three</p>", "<div>VVVV</div>"]];
                return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                });

            }).catch(function (e) {

            });

        })
        .catch(function (e) {

            console.log(e.message);
        });